# Regular Expression which validates that text box contain only English Characters in C# Asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, regex

Regular Expression Pattern for RegularExpressionValidator for matching English Characters is this

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 ~!@#$%^&*()_=?:;><.,`{}'/''[\\\]\r]*$
```

But this is not matching [Enter] or carriage return.

It is true for the sentence "I am a boy"

but not matching when sentence contain Enter or Carriage return \r for example

"I am a

boy"

What change is needed so that it will match strings containing carriage returns?

Comment: Add `\s` to the set (you can then remove 0x20 (space) and `\r`). But even with `\s` included, that's not _all_ English characters.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the operating system you may need to match on `\n` (new line / line feed) as well as `\r` (carriage return).

However, if you use `\s` you can match all white space characters: in JavaScript regexes `\s` is equivalent to `[ \f\n\r\t\v​\u00A0\u1680​\u180e\u2000​\u2001\u2002​\u2003\u2004​\u2005\u2006​\u2007\u2008​\u2009\u200a​\u2028\u2029​\u2028\u2029​\u202f\u205f​\u3000]`.

You may also like to use `\w`, which matches "word" characters, i.e., alphanumeric plus underscore.

Note that some English words contain hyphens so you should allow for that in your expression.